# возможно ли открыть запароленный SQLServerCE файл (.sdf) v3.5

Tags: delphi, reverse-engineering, sql-server-ce

Вот что удалось накопать

1. Программа (тест) запрашивает данные с сервера, после чего сохраняя в локальной базе SQLServerCE файл (data.sdf) v3.5...
2. Во время анализа в wireshark данные передаются в формате rtf.
3. При распаковке ( программы тест.exe) с помощью обычного архива,
   сама программа вроде бы упакована CodeGear RAD Studio 14.0, судя по файлу "манифест"
4. Также нашелся какой-то FastMM Borland Edition, вроде бы программа написана на delphi.
5. При попытке открыть файл data.sdf в CompactView запрашивает пароль. Возможно ли как то узнать или подобрать пароль?

Comment: `FastMM` это менеджер памяти. К базам данных отношения не имеет.

Comment: `CodeGear RAD Studio 14.0` это инструментарий на котором написана программа.(Если не ошибаюсь `Delphi 2010`)